# Topology-matching algorithm for finding 2D lattice in a 3D lattice

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, math, pattern-matching

I have a 3D lattice with a *unit cell* (i.e. the minimum repeating unit) of 16 points. Since it's a 3D lattice, it is periodic in all 3 dimensions (x, y, z). In detail, the unit cell looks like this:
[image]

The 3 *lattice vectors* **a**<sub>1</sub>, **a**<sub>2</sub>, **a**<sub>3</sub> are

```
bulk_vecs = [[14.56578026795, 0.0,            0.0          ], # a1
             [0.0,            8.919682340494, 0.0          ], # a2
             [7.282890133975, 2.973227446831, 4.20477857933]] # a3
```

The Cartesian coordinates of the 16 points are

```
bulk_coords = [[ 0.00000000,  0.00000000,  0.00000000],
               [ 10.9243352,  6.34420137,  2.66488775],
               [ 18.2072253,  6.34420137,  2.66488775],
               [ 12.7450577,  3.17210068,  1.33244387],
               [ 10.6807662,  8.91968234,  0.42187384],
               [ 16.1429338,  3.37097392,  1.19181926],
               [ 19.7843789,  9.31742882,  3.29420855],
               [ 9.34718165,  2.97322745,  1.47306849],
               [ 14.8093492,  6.34420137,  2.24301390],
               [ 9.10361267,  9.11855558,  3.43483316],
               [ 3.88501404,  0.39774648,  0.14062462],
               [ 7.03932116,  5.94645489,  2.52426313],
               [ 12.9886267,  8.91968234,  3.57545778],
               [ 7.28289013,  0.00000000,  0.00000000],
               [ 5.46216760,  3.17210068,  1.33244387],
               [ 16.3865028,  9.11855558,  3.43483316]]
```

Now I have a reference 2D lattice that contains 32 points in unit cell. Note that here "2D" means it is only periodic in the x and y dimensions, but can still have thickness in the z direction. Its unit cell looks like this (this is only a simple example, the unit cell can be of any shape, not necessarily cubic):

[image]

The 3 lattice vectors are given by

```
ref_vecs = [[8.1968234, 0.,          0.          ], # x-direction (periodic)
            [0.,        13.38535656, 0.          ], # y-direction (periodic)
            [0.,        0.,          7.7280392142]] # z-thickness (non-periodic)
```

The Cartesian coordinates of the 32 points are

```
ref_coords = [[ 5.65852755,  9.84826406,  0.10024035],
              [ 5.66769587,  3.14583318,  0.03049278],
              [ 5.84383908,  6.16622816,  0.33687635],
              [ 3.06154746,  11.5036515,  0.89497370],
              [ 3.04533245,  4.74684988,  0.80482405],
              [ 2.81714593,  7.85388222,  0.95654678],
              [ 3.09409158,  1.66514480,  1.21902173],
              [-0.03484920,  9.98872688,  1.91238251],
              [ 0.07586672,  6.55689489,  2.02252838],
              [ 0.15624468,  13.1218508,  2.07583316],
              [ 0.30441248,  2.82022739,  2.21046382],
              [ 5.46226670,  11.2187312,  2.95396399],
              [ 5.83993074,  5.03326172,  3.11251461],
              [ 5.40963696,  8.13117939,  3.23409626],
              [ 5.45612978,  1.47718658,  3.32634157],
              [ 2.72591886,  6.68506441,  3.86756751],
              [ 2.91602855,  3.06649570,  3.90688764],
              [ 2.95946887,  9.79329729,  3.96116732],
              [ 3.11916042,  12.9792231,  4.17677610],
              [ 0.35863087,  4.72533071,  4.75876360],
              [ 0.31594175,  11.4937246,  4.67355664],
              [ 0.03089551,  1.37091216,  4.91348486],
              [ 0.39020723,  8.35223658,  5.11836201],
              [ 5.45925351,  3.34155067,  5.87036690],
              [ 5.62981527,  13.2212649,  5.93479016],
              [ 5.64259931,  6.46196620,  5.93435713],
              [ 5.83825398,  9.54653517,  6.08472919],
              [ 2.80592452,  4.61964086,  6.76956275],
              [ 3.15087591,  11.6754589,  6.98585963],
              [ 2.68542186,  1.40293444,  7.10791606],
              [ 2.73378423,  8.13529985,  7.12898617],
              [ 0.03114729, -0.01057378,  7.78083813]]
```

This reference 2D lattice represents something similar to a "thick layer" extracted from a 3D lattice and its 2 lattice vectors in the x and y directions are **parallel** to **a**<sub>1</sub> and **a**<sub>2</sub> (i.e. parallel to the xy-plane). Now I want to find a parallel 2D lattice inside the current 3D lattice that best matches this reference 2D lattice. The similarity should depend on the **topology** of the two 2D lattice unit cells. For example, the reference unit cell could be thought as applying small perturbations to the fractional coordinates and lattice parameters of the best-matched 2D lattice unit cell. Below is an illustration for the 2D lattice extraction from the 3D lattice:
[image]

To search in the space of all possible parallel 2D lattice unit cells in a 3D lattice space is difficult, especially considering that I might need to expand the 3D lattice unit cell to search in the whole space (but how much should I expand?). I would like to know if there's any algorithm that can find the best topology-matching 2D lattice unit cell in the whole 3D lattice space relatively fast？ Specifically, I want to obtain the lattice vectors and the 32 Cartesian coordinates of the best-matched 2D lattice unit cell. Any sugguestions or even ideas are welcome.

## Edit:

OK I will try to explain the question in the simplest way possible. As you might have already guessed, I am working on crystallography. The 3D lattice represents a bulk crystal structure (i.e. periodic atom arrangement in all 3 dimensions) and a 2D lattice represents a surface structure (i.e. periodic atom arrangement in x and y directions, but has a non-periodic thick atom-layer in z direction). Obviously, a surface structure can be obtained by cutting the bulk structure.

Let's use a simple Si bulk structure (downloaded from [MaterialsProject](https://next-gen.materialsproject.org/materials/mp-149?chemsys=Si)) as an example, it has a cubic unit cell with 3 lattice vectors of

```
bulk_vecs = [[5.44370237, 0.0,        0.0       ],
             [0.0,        5.44370237, 0.0       ],
             [0.0,        0.0,        5.44370237]]
```

and atomic coordinates of

```
bulk_coords = [[ 1.27013575,  0.03307657, -0.02898786],
               [ 0.02039057,  0.02332397,  0.79145084],
               [ 0.0137774,   1.18012325,  1.85879242],
               [ 1.22267376,  1.27420799,  2.72875596],
               [ 1.20645874, -0.0488289,   3.52879259],
               [ 0.08487146, -0.06430577,  4.44147333]]
```

Diamond has the same type of crystal structure as Si, but slightly different lattice parameters and atomic coordinates. Now let's say I have a reference diamond(001) surface structure (the *Miller index* (001) basically means the surface plane is parallel to the xy-plane). It has a 6-atom unit cell, with 3 lattice vectors of

```
ref_vecs = [[2.5178270133578393, 0.0,                0.0        ],
            [0.0,                2.5178270133578393, 0.0        ],
            [0.0,                0.0,                5.341117665]]
```

and atomic coordinates of

```
ref_coords = [[ 1.27013575,  0.03307657, -0.02898786],
              [ 0.02039057,  0.02332397,  0.79145084],
              [ 0.0137774,   1.18012325,  1.85879242],
              [ 1.22267376,  1.27420799,  2.72875596],
              [ 1.20645874, -0.0488289,   3.52879259],
              [ 0.08487146, -0.06430577,  4.44147333]]
```

Since diamond has the same type of crystal structure as Si, one should be able to find a Si(001) surface unit cell from this reference diamond(001) surface unit cell. From what I could think of, a simple topology-matching algorithm could be to find a Si(001) surface unit cell in the bulk Si space, so that the sum of the fractional coordinate differences w.r.t. the reference diamond(001) surface unit cell is minimized. However, I am not sure how to search in such a large space, especially when the reference surface unit cell is large, one probably needs to expand the bulk unit cell by a lot, which means the search space becomes even larger.

For benchmarking purposes, I will provide the expected solution for the best-matched Si(001) surface unit cell. It should have lattice vectors close to

```
sol_vecs = [[3.8492788605882797, 0.0,                0.0        ],
            [0.0,                3.8492788605882797, 0.0        ],
            [0.0,                0.0,                8.165553555]]
```

and atomic coordinates close to

```
sol_coords = [[ 1.92463943, 0.0,        0.0       ],
              [ 0.0,        0.0,        1.36092562],
              [ 0.0,        1.92463943, 2.72185121],
              [ 1.92463943, 1.92463943, 4.08277680],
              [ 1.92463943, 0.0,        5.44370240],
              [ 0.0,        0.0,        6.80462799]]
```

[This](https://i.imgur.com/AeNAk1f.jpg) is an illustration of this problem in terms of crystallography (cannot upload to SO for some reason). As you can see in the figure, the Si(001) surface unit cell solution that I provided matches well with the reference diamond(001) surface unit cell.

Hint: working on the reciprocal space might be much easier than working on the real space.

## Final edit:

OK so let me rephrase the question in the most clear and simple way: **How to find a cell in the whole 3D lattice space where it contains the same number of points as the reference 2D lattice unit cell and has the minimum MAE/RMSE between the fractional coordinates of the two cells (i.e. Cartesian coordinates normalized by cell size)? The information we have is (1) the 3D lattice unit cell (2) the reference 2D lattice unit cell (3) the 2D lattice is parallel to the xy-plane of the 3D lattice**

Comment: Could you give us a simple example with 3d lattice being [1, 0, 0] [0,1,0] [0,0,1] (unit cubes in ordinary space), 2d lattice being something similar and fewer points, possibly with an example what you mean by the match similar by topology please? 
The problem you're solving looks interesting and I would love to give it a go. Unfortunately I'm having trouble with understanding what exactly do you mean and I would rather not go on a wild goose chase.

Comment: @Shamis I have updated my question. I used a simple cubic unit cell example. It's not necessary to use unit cubes, because one most likely needs to work on fractional coordinates anyway.

Comment: @Shamis I was trying to avoid using any chemistry terms in the original post, but found that it's probably easier to explain in chemistry terms. If you still have anything you don't understand, just let me know.

Comment: (based on a wild guess) I'm trying to play around with this problem in the Fourier domain. How should I interpret coordinates from ref_coords that fall outside of ref_vec? (After normalizing in the way that seems most obvious to me, I have some values slightly outside [0,1], e.g. 1.007 and -0.004)

Comment: @nanofarad Since it's periodic, 1.007 is equivalent to 0.007, and -0.004 is equivalent to 0.996

Comment: @nanofarad And yes you are on the right track. I think solving this problem definitely needs to look into the reciprocal space.

Comment: The bounty attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Comment: @nanofarad Hey I'm very interested in how's your Fourier transformation going?

Comment: @ShaunHan I haven't had a chance to play around with it yet extensively, unfortunately.

Comment: Another idea that popped into my head (remaining in the spatial domain rather than frequency domain) would be some adaptation (or possibly misuse) of RANSAC, but I haven't managed to adequately express the problem in terms of it yet.

Comment: I do not think you can get the *exact* solution in a *realistic* time. Indeed, the search space is huge, mainly due to the number of possible rotations/translations. Assuming someone give you a solution, you cannot say if this is the best solution without computing a better solution or the best. It means the problem is certainly not in the [NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)) class but PSPACE. The rotation makes analytic solutions far too complex to solve because of the non-trivial transformation. Any discretisation typically results in non-exact solutions.

Comment: The problem you want to solve seems to be the [**Rigid point-set registration**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-set_registration) except it is with lattices so it is a bit more complex (but there are some workarounds for this). Nearly all state-of-the art algorithms provides *approximated* solutions (though possibly good regarding the search space). I strongly recommand to read the linked page and state-of-the-art papers about this. This is rather a *research problem* (typically for a post-doc) than a just a programming one, so I do not expect any good answer here (in only few days).

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks for your illuminating comment. I am now trying to implement the iterative closest point (ICP) algorithm in lattices.

Answer (score 2):

#### Introduction

Let me rephrase the problem a little: We have a 3D pattern that fills the space with points. We have a reference plane that cuts this space basically anywhere, however we only know about the pattern the points in space create on the plane, nothing else.
Find the plane that best matches the reference plane.
To make matters worse, the pattern isn't fully 2D, it's more akin to a thin slice.

Fortunately for us, the number of points is rather limited so we can go for some brute-forcish approaches. However, we can't just compute all possible 2D lattices and find the one that matches the best, combinatorics would kill us. But we can do something similar and only bit more complicated.

#### Setting up the playground:

First let's generate the space we will be working in. To make things simple, let's extend the 3D lattice along all axes to generate a space large enough to fit in any given orientation and shift of the 2D lattice.
In our toy example, the 3D lattice vectors give us a cube and the 2D lattice vectors fit within this cube. So if we add a some padding on each side, this will cover all the possible rotations. Now if the reference 2D lattice is large or if the 3D lattice is skewed, this might not be enough so keep that in mind—it will likely require some math and stacking the lattices in a way that creates a space big enough to fit all possible rotations and translations of the reference 2D lattice. 
If we would **miss** the center 3D lattice, we can always snap back to it by claiming that whichever lattice we have biggest overlap with, is the new center piece.

Hopefully not too much to invalidate our follow up work.

##### Note:

If one lattice has 32 points, then we can use up to say 300 lattices to create our space. So far the worst part of the matching algorithm was quadratic so 10K * 10K * 2d_lattice_points computations should be doable. 300 latices gives us something like a 6x6x6 lattice cube. Also since we're concerned about the "flat and pointy" case, we're looking for some rectangle instead (for example, if the lattice was a 3x3x10, then we could do 10x10x3 stacking to compensate).

##### Note:

If the 3D lattice is skewed, I suggest cutting off the skewed part and prepending it to create a rectangle instead. This should be ok due to the periodic nature.

```
import numpy as np

bulk_vecs = np.array([[5.44370237, 0.0,        0.0       ],
                      [0.0,        5.44370237, 0.0       ],
                      [0.0,        0.0,        5.44370237]])

bulk_coords = np.array([[ 1.27013575,  0.03307657, -0.02898786],
                       [ 0.02039057,  0.02332397,  0.79145084],
                       [ 0.0137774,   1.18012325,  1.85879242],
                       [ 1.22267376,  1.27420799,  2.72875596],
                       [ 1.20645874, -0.0488289,   3.52879259],
                       [ 0.08487146, -0.06430577,  4.44147333]])

ref_vecs = np.array([[2.5178270133578393, 0.0,                0.0        ],
                    [0.0,                2.5178270133578393, 0.0        ],
                    [0.0,                0.0,                5.341117665]])

bulk_space = []
for point in [x for x in bulk_coords]:
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            for k in range(3):
                shift = i * bulk_vecs[0] + j * bulk_vecs[1] + k * bulk_vecs[2]
                bulk_space.append(point + shift)
```

This gives us some 162 points in the toy example which is fine. If this level of stacking is enough for the main case, this would give us some 432 points which is still ok. My hope is to do enough optimizations to be able to go up to low-thousands of points in the bulk space. (E.g., the 3D lattice generated playground.) 
Going much beyond that might be possible, but it will get annoying quickly—as I mentioned, I'm going to do some partial brute forcing.

#### Let the voodoo begin

First of all, let's get rid of all those pesky decimals. Computer's don't like them.
To do that, let us agree, that three decimals are enough for the precision (for now)

```
bulk_space = np.array(np.array(bulk_space) * 1000, dtype='longlong')
```

Note that this might be either too little or too much—I'm not sure about the actual level of deformation/imprecision that happens within the 2D plane. 
I will try to do some matching—if there are too many matches I will increase the precision. If too little (or none) I will decrease it. 
This is a discretization at its finest—we slice the continuous space (or finer, we already don't have full continuum in this case) into boxes of fixed size, and then say that every point matches to a box it is contained within. 
Then we forget all about the original points and happily compute away with the boxes. 
Finally if we succeed in our endeavor, we go back to the points and try to upgrade the precision.

##### Note:

From what I got it seems that the chosen precision doesn't result in any overlaps of points (two points within the cube)—the space we're working in doesn't seem to be too densely populated. If two (or more) points overlap we don't mind too much. However it means that in the final check (while increasing the precision) we need to check every one of them with our solution.

#### Plane approximation:

Since we don't have knowledge about the 2D plane orientation, we will use the distance matching first. We will compute a distance matrix of the 3D space and store it away.

Then we will compute the distance matrix for the 2D lattice, and take the longest distance, since it will repeat itself the least due to limited space in the 3D-lattice based box.

Then we will take one of its endpoints and take all the distances to other points and sort them.

##### Note:

We're going to be comparing distances and we don't actually care about their values, only their comparisons, we can omit the square roots and work with distances squared. It is cheaper computation wise.

Now we will search for matches of the largest distance in both 2D and 3D. For every match, we will then try to find a matching sequence of distances.

##### Note 2:

For checking the existence of the match, we can sort the distance array corresponding to the point, find the matching maximum (which we already know that it's there from the previous point) and then find the rest in order—if we don't find any given match, we can discard the whole sequence since it's sorted. 
Note that we either need to keep indices while sorting (which is sort of annoying) or  brute-search for the matches after we confirm their existence to infer the indices from the matrix (which takes a bit time—but not too much, only number of 2D-based points times the number of 3D points). 
So we will do that.

##### Note 3:

If we don't find any match due to the imprecision of the 2D lattice cut, we can try again with lower precision until we find it.

##### Note 4:

We don't care about finding multiple matches at this points. We're just filtering/validating the points. We will handle these in the next step.

```
for i in range(len(ref_space)):
    for j in range(i, len(ref_space)):
        diff = ref_space[i] - ref_space[j]
        dist = np.sum(diff * diff)
        distance_matrix_2d[i, j] = dist
        distance_matrix_2d[j, i] = dist
        if dist > distance_max_2d:
            dmax_i = i
            dmax_j = j
            distance_max_2d = dist

distance_matrix_3d = np.zeros(shape=[len(bulk_space), len(bulk_space)], dtype='longlong')
match_list_i = []
match_list_j = []
point_match = []
dist_min = 1000000000
dist_max = 0
for i in range(len(bulk_space)):
    for j in range(i, len(bulk_space)):
        diff = bulk_space[i] - bulk_space[j]
        dist = np.sum(diff * diff)
        distance_matrix_3d[i, j] = dist
        distance_matrix_3d[j, i] = dist
        if distance_max_2d - dist == 0:
            match_list_i.append(i)
            match_list_j.append(j)
            point_match.append(i)
            point_match.append(j)

point_matches = []
for i in point_match:
    x = []
    for j in range(len(distance_matrix_3d)):
        x.append(distance_matrix_3d[i, j])
    x = np.sort(x)
    point_matches.append((i, x))
# Note that we're currently not using the sort
# and I'm simply brute forcing the next step.
# If that is an issue, this sort can be used to
# make the next step log(n) * 2d_pts_count
# by checking first the existence of the
# distance via binary search in the 3D
# sorted matrix.
# However since we only have few 2D points, this
# is likely unnecessary unless we're solving
# some big case, where there might be other
# performance bottlenecks.

point_matches_bruteforce = []
for i, matches in point_matches:
    # Check all the rows defined by points from the previous
    # step (selected by matching the longest distance)
    row_failed = False
    for dist2d in distance_matrix_2d[dmax_i]:
        # For every distance in 2D matrix,
        # try finding a matching one
        found = False
        for dist3d in matches:
            # If we find it, we qualify the distance
            if dist3d == dist2d:
                found = True
        #print("dist2d checked")
        if not found:
            # If we didn't find any match, we can discard
            # the point. There is at least one point from
            # the set without matching distance, e.g.,
            # we can't match the structure.
            row_failed = True
            break
    if row_failed:
        # If any row failed (no matching 3D distance
        # for a 2D one, we discard the point)
        print("point ", i, "has failed to find matching set")
    else:
        # Otherwise, we keep it for the next, more bruteforcish round
        print("point ", i, "is a candidate")
        point_matches_bruteforce.append(i)
```

#### Finding the points:

We have now filtered the 3D candidate list and it's time to find whether any of them match our 2D lattice. For this we will use the triangle identity: two triangles are identical, if **all their sides are identical.**

How will we do that?

We already have the distances matrix for both 2D and 3D. Furthermore, we have the starting point with its possible neighbors. So for every such starting point, we will check whether the distances of neighbors are matching. This will take us some time—number_of_2d_points * number_or_3d_points if we don't do any optimizations.

#### Note:

There might be some pathological edge cases where this will find too many matches. There is always one optimization possible: sort the distances, then use binary search for matching, reducing the time from n to log(n) per point to be checked at the cost of the initial sort. 
Annoying part is that it will shuffle around indices so you will need to note them down and keep track of them.

##### The algorithm:

- take the starting point
- find its potential neighbors via distance check (number_of_2d_points * number_of_3d_points)

  - note that there might be duplicates. We will get rid of them ASAP to prevent combinatorial explosion
  - go over (potential) neighbors one by one
  - for every neighbor

    - check distance to all other already checked neighbors
    - if all match, continue onto next neighbor
    - otherwise discard this branch (if there are more potential neighbors with this distance, try the next one, otherwise discard the starting point)
  - if we matched all neighbors, we just found one potential set of matching points. (minus the imprecision due to the initial rounding, so we note it down)

##### Note:

I will try to get back to it and provide code and potentially benchmark and optimize. However, I'm afraid I already spent too much time and I have some duties to attend to.

### What now?

Now we should have a set (or several) of 3D matching structures. If we didn't find one, we lower the precision and try again. If we found more than one, we can now increase the precision and look (or compute) which of the candidates is the best match—this should be rather straightforward as we already have 1:1 mapping between points from the previous step. (Keeping track of the indices will be a bit of a pain though.)

When we have the best match, the last step to do is to find the 2D lattice orientation. We have: set of points in 3D (matrix P3d), the 2D lattice point coordinates (matrix P2d) and the lattice (matrix L2d). 
Dimension of matrices P2d and P3d are identical. 
So now we're looking for such a matrix L3d, how do we to that? 
We need to find a matrix X such that X * P2d = P3d 
Then we do X * L2d = L3d.

##### Note:

There is one edge case where this will not work—if you find a structure, where the 2D structure is a mirror image of the 3D one, rotation to find a match won't be possible. It should be reasonably easy to spot if you plot it though. Alternatively there is likely some math to find this case.

And we're done.

If I have more time, I will try to finish this up in code and test it properly and possibly optimize. Not sure when I can get to it though. Please let me know if this was sufficiently helpful or if you need me to explain any part more in depth. 
Also, if it works, please let me know how it went :-).

### Edit:

To answer your questions:

1. I already had some ideas about this one and listed them above, however now I'm uncertain due to the size differences. I will try to briefly sum them up.

   - Normalize both lattices
   - Take the 3D lattice and compute its bounding vertices and edges.
   - Take the longest dimension of the 2D lattice 2d_long (e.g., length of the line segment connecting two vertices that are furthest one another)
   - Compute the following bounding box:

     - min_x = min_coord_x - 2d_long
     - max_x = max_coord_x + 2d_long
     - same for y and z
   - Now fill this bounding box with copies of lattice 3D. This should be rather straightforward to compute. This should be enough and hopefully not too large.
2. Ok, normalize by cell size, that shouldn't be a problem, rest should work as described. It will impact the precision so you might need to use only two decimals and subsequently will have more matches
3. Neighbors in **graph** sense.

   - I create a fully completed graph (clique) on the vertices in the 2D lattice and assign edges to have weight equal to length.
   - Then for the 3D matrix I do the same, except I discard the edges that are not matched—e.g., have a length different from any of the 2D ones.
   - Finally I check if there is a matching subgraph in the 3D space.
4. You can consider the angle matching however if you can normalize with sufficient precision it is not needed—we're checking for identical triangles and those have matching angles by the virtue of being identical.

   - We expect there are multiple matches—in fact, in the toy example, there are six matching "starting" points. That doesn't matter—we will simply check them and eliminate those that don't lead to the desired structure.

Comment: Hi @Shamis , thanks for your efforts. Regarding your answer, I have the following questions: 1. Is there a smart way of knowing how much we should expand the 3D lattice space based on the size of the reference 2D lattice unit cell? I want a general solution so I don't want to use a huge 3D space for even a tiny reference 2D lattice unit cell.

Comment: 2. I'm not sure about Euclidean distance matching, because this will give wrong matches when the reference surface has quite different unit cell size. In [this](https://i.imgur.com/qus1MZU.jpg) illustration for example, the diamond(001) cell is actually much smaller than Si(001) unit cell, but the **topology** (including cell shape, and the arrangement of atoms) looks very similar. For example, Si(001) cell can be  2cm x 2cm x 4cm, and the Diamond(001) cell could be 3cm x 3cm x 6cm. IMO we should compare the **fractional** coordinates/distances, i.e. normalized by the cell size.

Comment: 3. How do you define "neighbors"? Do you manually set a cutoff, or you mean the nearest point equals neighbor?

Comment: 4. Let's say I have matched the first point, if I want to match the next point by distance, there is a high chance that there will be multiple points that have the same distance to this point (due to the high symmetry of crystal structures). Now if we want a new match, we need to consider not just the distance, but also the angle/orientation of the vectors. IMO a topology matching between two entire point clouds is probably easier and faster than a sequential matching approach

Comment: And that is why I originally asked about making the question more specific ^^. I will answer your question in an edit.

Comment: The problem with the 2nd issue is that, how do you normalize distance in the 3D lattice space if you don't know the unit cell size of the best-matched 2D lattice?

Comment: Note that you cannot normalize using the 3D lattice unit cell, because it has a completely different size compared to the best-matched 2D lattice unit cell which we are searching for. And you can only compare the normalized distances between the reference 2D lattice unit cell and the 2D lattice unit cell we are searching for.

Comment: Feels like you're moving the goal post or didn't specify the question enough. If you don't know the 2D lattice unit size it makes it basically impossible to answer question 1), since you have no way of estimating how big space you need to fit your 2d lattice into.

Comment: @Shamis Based on my recollection, when I first started experimenting with frequency-domain methods a few days ago, it was fairly clear that you didn't know the 2D lattice unit size and had to estimate it as well

Comment: @Shamis I have stated in the post that the reference 2D lattice unit cell may have "different lattice paramters". That means exactly a different unit cell size.

Comment: I will give you the bounty thanks to your effort. I have found a solution, which is to use a [scale-adaptive iterative closet point (ICP) algorithm](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1524070321000187). I will post an answer once I finish the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a 3D point cloud (lattice or not) with `N3` points and a 2D plane with `N2` points. And let's also say they are at the same scale, not that one group can be "zoomed" to fit the other.

And the goal is determine wether the `N2` points can be found among the `N3` points, after some translation and rotation common to all `N2` points.

Let's take the first point (p1) in 2D group and by the method you like (perhaps a triangulation fits well) you get the nearest neighbour `p2` to `p1`. Calculate its distance `d12` (or its square, to save sqrt calculations).

Now suppose we have a point `ss` in 3D group that satisfies it has a 3D neighbour `sn` at that same `d12` distance, with some tolerance error. It's not needed to be the closest point; in fact it can be any other point in 3D group, but likely it's somehow a neigbour of `ss`.

Perhaps you have to traverse the whole 3D group to find such `ss`point. If you can't find one, then no, the 2D slide doesn't belong to 3D group.

Now we have a match you can align vector (p1, p2) with vector (ss, sn). This can be achieved by multiplicating two matrices, so any point in 2D system can be transformed into 3D coordinates system.

We have aligned one axis but for the other two we need at least one more point.

Get the next closest neigbour to  `p1`, call it `p3`. Calculates distances d13, d23.

Find neighbours in 3D that, again, satisfy the same distances.

Again, no matching, no solution.

If you have p1,p2,p3 and ss,sn,sc then you can rotate around the already aligned axis to get a third matrix, which multiplied by the others achieves the "direct transformation" from 2D to 3D systems.

The rest is easy. Use that matrix with the rest of pj points in 2D and search in 3D for the same (now transformed) coordinates, always with some allowed error.

Notice I've used closest neighbours, just for better understanding. But the method should work with any point sequence you like.

**NOTE**

When looking for points in 3D group you may find not only one, but several "solutions" (that's crystallography). You must store them, and check later, likey at "rest of 2D" points state.

And you may also find that there are several 2D into 3D matches, again due to atoms configuration.

Also, perhaps the 2D plane matches partially (eg, at the left and at the right, but not in the center). To avoid this I'd expand the unit 3D cell, so I use a 3x3x3 3D group repeating the unit cell. This way covers all 2D positions, overlapping in two different 3D unit cells.